# JodConverter throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jodconverter

I've a problem with JODConverter , the NoClassDefFoundError.. I'm using netbeans 7.1.2 , jdk 1.7 , jodconverter2.2.2.jar and openoffice 3.3.0.. I'm building a java enterprise application and in the ejb section i'm adding the jodconverter2.2.2.jar library (right click to the ejb project , properties , library add jar/folder).. But when i run the application and i want to convert a .doc file :

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: message-driven bean method public abstract void javax.jms.MessageListener.onMessage(javax.jms.Message) system exception
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1134)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)
at $Proxy271.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:114)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/lang/XEventListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:756)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:756)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at managers.ElaboraDisp.converteInPdf(ElaboraDisp.java:145)
at managers.ElaboraDisp.onMessage(ElaboraDisp.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1099)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.star.lang.XEventListener
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 42 more

Avvertenza: MDB00037: [UploadMultiplo:ElaboraDisp]: Message-driven bean invocation exception: [javax.ejb.EJBException]
Avvertenza: javax.ejb.EJBException
javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDeliveryInternal(MessageBeanContainer.java:1211)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanContainer.java:1186)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:86)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:143)
at $Proxy271.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:114)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/lang/XEventListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:756)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:756)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at managers.ElaboraDisp.converteInPdf(ElaboraDisp.java:145)
at managers.ElaboraDisp.onMessage(ElaboraDisp.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1099)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)
at $Proxy271.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:260)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.star.lang.XEventListener
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 42 more


Avvertenza: MQJMSRA_MR2001: run:Caught Exception from onMessage():Redelivering:
javax.ejb.EJBException: message-driven bean method public abstract void javax.jms.MessageListener.onMessage(javax.jms.Message) system exception
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1134)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)
at $Proxy271.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:114)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/connection/SocketOpenOfficeConnection
at managers.ElaboraDisp.converteInPdf(ElaboraDisp.java:145)
at managers.ElaboraDisp.onMessage(ElaboraDisp.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1099)
... 7 more

Informazioni: MQJMSRA_MR1101: run:Message returned & marked for routing to the DMQ
Avvertenza: MDB00037: [UploadMultiplo:ElaboraDisp]: Message-driven bean invocation    exception: [javax.ejb.EJBException]
Avvertenza: javax.ejb.EJBException
javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDeliveryInternal(MessageBeanContainer.java:1211)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanContainer.java:1186)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.afterMessageDelivery(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:86)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:143)
at $Proxy271.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:114)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/connection/SocketOpenOfficeConnection
at managers.ElaboraDisp.converteInPdf(ElaboraDisp.java:145)
at managers.ElaboraDisp.onMessage(ElaboraDisp.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1099)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)
at $Proxy271.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:260)
... 3 more
```

The code of the conversion is standard:

```java
    File inputFile=new File("document.doc");
    File outputFile=new File("document.pdf");
    OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
    connection.connect();

    // convert
    DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
    converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

    // close the connection
    connection.disconnect();
```

Into the terminal :

```
soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard
```

I don't understand why i've the exception :(

PS. into the war section i'm adding a folder "lib" with the library (jodconverter2.2.2.jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError exception is thrown when the class is not found in classpath. So if you are trying to access this class in ejb it has to be available to it.

If you added lib folder in your .war file, the ejb .jar can not see lib folder placed under .war file.

You need to create lib folder in your .ear file and in application.xml file specify that library directory is for both: your web application .war and ejb .jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">
    <display-name>yourapp</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>yourapp-ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>yourapp.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

This line `<library-directory>lib</library-directory>` specifies that your lib directory is in .ear archive. Also you need to remove lib folder from your .war file.

Comment: I create the application.xml file (and paste it in the configuration files folder of the general module of the project), I remove the WEB-INF/lib folder in war module , and checked if exist the lib folder in .ear file..  doesn't work :(...

Comment: Or did you check if your application.xml exists in .ear META-INF directory?

Comment: I accept the answer but it isn't the solution at my problem...i solved the problem by moving the library and the code (that work with this library) in the war module , there aren't exceptions..later i moved back (the library and the code) to the ejb module and it's work!! incredible!